# Any way can add click event to child nodes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code:

```
<div class="sidebar-list">
  <h4>Type</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id='shop'>   Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='food'>   Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='beauty'> Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='comfort'>Comfort</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='health'> Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='pet'>    Pet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='fun'>    Fun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='life'>   Life</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I know I can write o'clock to each li item but any smart way to add event listen to listen list item of sidebar-list list is clicked and get value of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```js
$('.sidebar-list').on('click', 'li', function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-list">
  <h4>Type</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id='shop'>   Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='food'>   Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='beauty'> Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='comfort'>Comfort</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='health'> Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='pet'>    Pet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='fun'>    Fun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='life'>   Life</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. by the way, any way I can get the id value of a tag in this function?

Comment: @aBloomer just use `$(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').delegate('a', 'click', function() {
  // ... your code ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this? See Fiddle below. 
A simple jQuery click event...

```js
$('.sidebar-list li').click(function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-list">
  <h4>Type</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" id='shop'>   Shop</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='food'>   Food</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='beauty'> Beauty</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='comfort'>Comfort</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='health'> Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='pet'>    Pet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='fun'>    Fun</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id='life'>   Life</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.querySelector(".sidebar-list"),
    addEvent = ( obj, type, fn ) => {
      if ( obj.attachEvent ) {
        obj['e'+type+fn] = fn;
        obj[type+fn] = function(){obj['e'+type+fn]( window.event );}
        obj.attachEvent( 'on'+type, obj[type+fn] );
      } else
        obj.addEventListener( type, fn, false );
    };
addEvent(div, "click", (ev) => {
    var event = ev || window.event;
        target = event.target || event.srcElement;
    // do something with your target
});
```

No need of jQuery if it's not already used in your page (note that the polyfill is from the author of jQuery...)